# ChimpChat on android

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am using `ChimpChat` for an automation project. The ChimpChat instance is declared within an `JUnit` test case. I have added `sdklib/chimpchat/ddmlib/guava-13.0.1/jars` to the `libs` folder. While running the JUnit test case, I get the below exception. Could anyone help me out on this.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.SdkConstants
```

Comment: have you linked lib in project properties?

Comment: hi piotrpo, I have not linked lib in project properties file in android. Because it is an auto-generated file, any modification that I make on the file gets erased.

Answer (score 1):

Add common.jar library for SdkConstants.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.